# Apache POI XSSFColor from hex code

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to set the foreground color of a cell to a given color in hex code. For example, when I try to set it to red:

```
style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(Color.decode("#FF0000")).getIndexed());
```

No matter what Hex value I set in the parameter for the decode function, the getIndexed function will always return the black color.

Could it be that I might be doing something wrong? I think it's a bug but I'm not sure...

Comment: why do you need getIndexed()? For backward compatibility?? Try removing that.

Comment: If you apply the style to a cell, does it correctly show up as red in Excel?

Comment: I need getindexed because the method will only accept a short value.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The good news is, if you are using XSSF, as opposed to HSSF, then the solution to your problem is fairly easy. You simply have to cast your style variable to XSSFCellStyle.  If you do, then there is a version of setFillForegroundColor that takes an XSSFColor argument, so you need not call getIndexed(). Here is some example code:

```
XSSFCellStyle style = (XSSFCellStyle)cell.getCellStyle();
XSSFColor myColor = new XSSFColor(Color.RED);
style.setFillForegroundColor(myColor);
```

However, if you are using HSSF, then things are harder. HSSF uses a color palette, which is simply an array of colors. The short value that you pass into setFillForegroundColor is an index into the palette.

So the problem you have is converting an rgb value into a palette index. The solution you proposed, using getIndexed(), is logical, but, unfortuntately, it does work for XSSFColor the way you might suppose it should.

Fortunately, there is a solution. For the moment, let us assume you will be satisfied using one of the colors in the default palette, rather than using a custom color. In that case, you can use the HSSFPalette and HSSFColor classes to solve the problem. Here is some example code:

```
HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFPalette palette = hwb.getCustomPalette();
// get the color which most closely matches the color you want to use
HSSFColor myColor = palette.findSimilarColor(255, 0, 0);
// get the palette index of that color 
short palIndex = myColor.getIndex();
// code to get the style for the cell goes here
style.setFillForegroundColor(palIndex);
```

If you want to use custom colors not already in the default palette, then you have to add them to the palette. The javadoc for HSSFPalette defines the methods you can use for doing so.

Comment: I was using XSSF, so the first solution made the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This `palette.findSimilarColor(255, 0, 0);` saved me from madness. Thank you so much. Of course upvoted.

Comment: The above code did not work until i created the style from the workbook instead of getting that from the cell like @JonathanL answer below

Comment: new XSSFColor(Color.RED) is now deprecated.

Answer (score 36):

For Apache POI prior to 4.0 you can simply do the following :

```
 XSSFColor grey = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(192,192,192));
 cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(grey);
```

Since POI 4.0 you have to provide the workbench IndexedColorMap:

```
 IndexedColorMap colorMap = workbook.getStylesSource().getIndexedColors();
 XSSFColor grey = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(192,192,192), colorMap);
 cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(grey);
```

Comment: this works too and gives easy way of applying RGB color to a cell

Comment: Just note this might break your server because of dependencies to AWT classes and the server might be headless. Didn't check it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the hint concerning POI 4.0! I am migrating from 3.17 to 4.0.0 and was wondering where to get that IndexedColorMap from because the constructor XSSFColor(Color) I was using has been removed.

Comment: Thx. It's the only example I found for poi 4.0

Comment: Thanks for the POI 4.0 Example. That helped me a lot. The only change I propose is, that you cannot add a XSSFColor but you have to add the **.getIndex()**: `cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(grey.getIndex())`

Comment: This makes the cell black no matter what rgb values you use.

Comment: Hello, I am using poi 4.0.1 and my ide does not recognize getStyleSources() from workbook.getStylesSource().getIndexedColors(). What import do you need for that? I am importing the following, but no luck: 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.IndexedColorMap;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable;

Answer (score 18):

Use `XSSFColor` for `XSSFWorkbook`. `XSSFColor` can take `byte[] rgb` or a `java.awt.Color`.
See examples below:

1. ```
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
   XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
   byte[] rgb = new byte[3];
   rgb[0] = (byte) 242; // red
   rgb[1] = (byte) 220; // green
   rgb[2] = (byte) 219; // blue
   XSSFColor myColor = new XSSFColor(rgb); // #f2dcdb
   cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(myColor);
   cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
   ```
2. see GuenSeven's answer

   ```
   XSSFColor myColor = new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(242, 220, 219)); // #f2dcdb
   cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(myColor);
   cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
   ```

Comment: I am not able to use .setFillForegroundColor(myColor); what do i do?

Comment: @meme, upgrade to poi version 3.0.7 or later, I use version 3.10

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to use AWTs Color, and since there is no constructor that solely accepts a byte array nowadays (I'm using version 3.17): There is a constructor `public XSSFColor(byte[] rgb, IndexedColorMap colorMap)`, which did the trick for me:

```
byte[] byteColor = new byte[]{255,0,0};
XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(byteColor, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to get a XSSFColor from a String hex color (FFEEDDCC or 112233 format). If you are using RGB, simply remove # character:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(workbook.getStylesSource().getIndexedColors());
color.setARGBHex("#000000".substring(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

XSSFCellStyle accept color in method setFillForegroundColor for poi version above 3.07 ... so check your version first to avoid getting in the problem I was facing ... previous version needed short as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(new Color(0xFF0000), null);
style.setFillForegroundColor(color);
```