# Unable to set fill background color for certain cell using RGB value in apache POI

Tags: apache-poi, background-color, rgb, xssf

I'm using XSSF in Apache POI to generate Xlsx file.
I imported `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor`. My purpose is to set fill background color to `RGB(141,180,226)` for certain cell.
I tried using

```
XSSFColor bg=getXSSFColor("8DB4E2");
```

to get the codes for the color first.
Then use,

```
setFillBackgroundColor(bg)
```

to set the color.
However, method `getXSSFColor` cannot be found.
I don't know why and if there is other to achieve the same purpose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10924483/1211000,it may help u