# How do I change the Text Color and the Fillcolor

Tags: java, apache-poi

How do I change the header font color to white and the fill green?  These are the classes that I am using:

```
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle.*
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font
```

And this is the code where, I believe, it will have to be inserted into.

```
Font headerFont = wb.createFont();
headerFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD)
CellStyle headerStyle = wb.createCellStyle()
headerStyle.setFont(headerFont)

cellMOPID.setCellStyle(headerStyle)
cellType.setCellStyle(headerStyle)
cellStatus.setCellStyle(headerStyle)
cellState.setCellStyle(headerStyle)
cellStartDate.setCellStyle(headerStyle)
cellEndDate.setCellStyle(headerStyle)
cellDesc.setCellStyle(headerStyle)
```

Answer (score 17):

```
     HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();        
     HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
     font.setFontName(XSSFFont.DEFAULT_FONT_NAME);
     font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)10);
     font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
     cellStyle.setFont(font);
    //the version i am using is poi-3.8
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to set the color as simple cellstyle... you can write code like.

```
 cell.setCellValue("Header Text");
 XSSFCellStyle headerStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
 Font headerFont = wb.createFont();
 headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
 headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
 headerStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
 headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
 cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
```

This will fill the cell with GREEN color and the font will be of Bold WHITE color

Comment: Which jar file is the XSSFCellStyle located in?  This looks like what I need!

Comment: I am using apache poi 3.9. XSSFCellStyle is located in org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle

Comment: I list import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle at the top of my document but I get an "unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle" message.  Does this mean that I do not have it?

Comment: The problem might be because you are using HSSF and with xls file. I was using XSSF and for xlsx file. If it is not altering your requirement, shift on xlsx file and use XSSF. and if you need xls file then remain on HSSF. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/10924483/624003 will help you to get it.

Comment: There is no need to migrate from HSSF to XSSF with out any specific memory issues.U can apply Color for font using hssf also.

Comment: @swamy - Can you give an example using the original code above?

Comment: BTW Jonathan... Which version of POI you are using right now.

Comment: I am using version 3.9

Comment: Please check the proposed solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17709121/624003

Answer (score 9):

For xls file I have checked the following and is working fine on my end.

I need to import following:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
```

and the piece of code is following:

```
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream (XLSFileAddress);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fin);
    HSSFCell cell=wb.getSheetAt(2).getRow(0).getCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Header Text");
    Font headerFont = wb.createFont();
    headerFont.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
    CellStyle headerStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    headerStyle.setFont(headerFont);
    headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
    headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
    headerStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(XLSFileAddress);
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

The output of this code is the first cell of first Row of sheet at index two, will show the text **"Header Text"** with **cell color as Green and Text Color is White with Bold Font**.

I am using apache POI 3.9.