# Fill color in hssf cell

Tags: apache-poi, hssf

I have been adding background as shown below. All other changes are seen in the excel but cell does not get filled with the color. please help

```
public static CellStyle getWeeklyHeaderStyle(HSSFWorkbook wb) {

    CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setWrapText(true);
    cellStyle.setAlignment((short) 1);
    cellStyle.setVerticalAlignment((short) 1);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft((short) 1);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight((short) 1);
    cellStyle.setBorderTop((short) 1);
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom((short) 1);
    getPalette(wb);
    cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
    cellStyle.setFont(getFont(wb));
    return cellStyle;
}

public static HSSFPalette getPalette(HSSFWorkbook wb) {

    HSSFPalette palette = wb.getCustomPalette();
    // replacing the standard red with freebsd.org red
    palette.setColorAtIndex(IndexedColors.RED.index, (byte) 204, (byte) 204,
            (byte) 255);
    return palette;
}
```

Comment: Use `setFillForegroundColor` instead of `setFillBackgroundColor`   check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17709121/624003

Comment: i have even tried that. but its working i am stuck up in a bad way.

Comment: i have even tried that. but its nt working. please help me as i am stuck badly.

Comment: You have written a method which is returning `cellstyle`... but you have not used `cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);` that is used to deploy the cellstyle to the selected cell.

Comment: yeah i have that method in a different class. all other that have been mentioned above are getting applied. even the font which i have it myself. but the color is not getting filled.

Comment: thnx for ur help. but i have done it by adding cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);thnx anyways