# Custom background color in conditional formatting using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a XSSF workbook and I want to define a custom background color in a set of cells with a conditional formatting defined, but the problem is that the `setFillBackgroundColor()` method in the `PatternFormatting` class only accepts a type short argument, not a `XSSFColor` like this:

```java
PatternFormatting fill = rule1.createPatternFormatting();
fill.setFillBackgroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(80, 80, 100));
fill.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

I can do `fill.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.index)`, but I want to define a custom color. How can i do this?.

Comment: that `fill.setFillBackgroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(80, 80, 100));` is custom R=80 G=80 B=100 right? what is the problem by using that?

Comment: @Angga The problem is the `setFillBackgroundColor()` method in the `PatternFormatting` class only accepts a type short argument, not a `XSSFColor`.

Comment: related: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10912578/apache-poi-xssfcolor-from-hex-code

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still reading this and having the problem the requester describes back in 2014, you are probably on a version of Apache POI before 3.13. Try upgrading to at least 3.13 where you should indeed be able to do:

```
fill.setFillBackgroundColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(80, 80, 100))
```

(see also here: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56774)