# Not able to set custom color in XSSFCell Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am trying to set some custom(from hexcode or rgb value) color to a xssfcell.But the color of the cell is becoming black even though I am giving some other color.I have tried doing this by the following ways :

```
File xlSheet = new File("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Downloads\\Excel Test\\Something3.xlsx");
    System.out.println(xlSheet.createNewFile());
    FileOutputStream fileOutISPR = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Downloads\\Excel Test\\Something3.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook isprWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = isprWorkbook.createSheet("TEST");
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = isprWorkbook.createCellStyle();
    byte[] rgb = new byte[3];
    rgb[0] = (byte) 24; // red
    rgb[1] = (byte) 22; // green
    rgb[2] = (byte) 219; // blue
    XSSFColor myColor = new XSSFColor(rbg);
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(myColor);
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    cellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has");
    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    CellRangeAddress rangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, 2);
    sheet.addMergedRegion(rangeAddress);
    int width = ((int)(90 * 0.73)) * 256;
    sheet.setColumnWidth(cell.getColumnIndex(), width);
    //sheet.autoSizeColumn(cell.getColumnIndex());
    RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM, rangeAddress, sheet, isprWorkbook);
    RegionUtil.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex(), rangeAddress, sheet, isprWorkbook);

    XSSFCell cell2 = row.createCell(11);
    cell2.setCellValue("222222222222222");
    isprWorkbook.write(fileOutISPR);
```

//END of the program

```
   XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = isprWorkbook.createCellStyle();
   byte[] rgb = new byte[3];
    rgb[0] = (byte) 24; // red
    rgb[1] = (byte) 22; // green
    rgb[2] = (byte) 219; // blue
    XSSFColor myColor = new XSSFColor(rgb);
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(myColor);//1st method
    //cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(new   java.awt.Color(128, 0, 128)));//2nd method  
  //XSSFColor myColor = new XSSFColor(Color.decode("0XFFFFFF"));
  cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(myColor);//3rd Method
```

I tried many other ways mentioned in answers to related questions but none of those solved my problem.
Please help me out.

Comment: it's the morning here but what is the difference between 1 and 3 ? I think you are missing a fill pattern, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31671032/180100

Comment: Sure,I'll update the question with minimal code.Thank you

Comment: fill pattern is not missing in the code and if fill pattern was missing the cell would be full white even after setting the color.But in my case,full cell is black.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959440/apache-poi-fills-xssf-cell-with-black-instead-of-desired-custom-color-when-apply. Problem is using `RegionUtil` for setting borders. But  `org.apache.poi.ss.util.*` is `SS` and not `XSSF` and `SS` cannot use `XSSFColor` only color indexes are possible.

Comment: @AxelRichter : thanks,its working now.But,is there any way that I can use RegionUtil in my code because I have to use it for giving the outer border of a table?

Comment: @AxelRichter you should make that an answer

Comment: Apache 4.0.0 answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52926591/5611377

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is caused by an incompleteness of [Package org.apache.poi.ss.util](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/package-summary.html).

`PropertyTemplate` as well as `CellUtil` and `RegionUtil`are be based on `ss.usermodel` level only and not on `xssf.usermodel` level. But [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html) does not know something about a `setFillForegroundColor(Color color)` until now. It only knows `setFillForegroundColor(short bg)`. So `ss.usermodel` level simply cannot set a `Color` as fill foreground color until now. Only a `short` (a color index) is possible.

If it comes to the question why setting the color is necessary when only the border shall be set using `org.apache.poi.ss.util` then the answer is, it is necessary because both, color and border, are in the same `CellStyle`. Thats why when adding the border settings to the `CellStyle`, the color settings must be maintain and finally be set new.

So in conclusion, there is not a way out of this dilemma. If you need using `org.apache.poi.ss.util` then you cannot use `setFillForegroundColor(XSSFColor color)` the same time. The only hope is `setFillForegroundColor(Color color)` will be added to `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle` in later versions of  `apache poi`.

Comment: Can you raise this as an enhancement request in the Apache POI bugzilla, so it doesn't get forgotten? Bonus marks for a patch too.... :)

Comment: 3 years later and this still hasn't been addressed. :(

Comment: Just letting everyone know that this has been fixed in version 5.2.3

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use conditional formatting to set custom colors after you've set all other format options (alignment, borders...) with cell style.

Here is a working (Kotlin) example that defines a custom color to distinguish between even and odd rows:

```
private fun setEvenOddColorFormatting(sheet: XSSFSheet) {
            val sheetConditionalFormatting = sheet.sheetConditionalFormatting

            val rule = sheetConditionalFormatting.createConditionalFormattingRule("MOD(ROW(), 2) = 0")
            val formatForRule = rule.createPatternFormatting()
            formatForRule.setFillBackgroundColor(XSSFColor(byteArrayOf(221.toByte(), 235.toByte(), 247.toByte())))
            formatForRule.fillPattern = PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND

            val region = arrayOf(CellRangeAddress(0, sheet.lastRowNum,0,10))
            sheetConditionalFormatting.addConditionalFormatting(region, rule)
        }
```

A drawback is, that you have to write the rule as excel function. But you should be able to use an always true function and only set the region.