# Apache POI: RegionUtil XSSF Bordercolor selection for merged regions (based on awt.Color)?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i'm currently adding merged regions to my `xlsx` files using `Apache POI`. I'm using the `RegionUtil` to create borders for merged cells spanning multiple columns and rows.

The part about selecting the correct borderstyle works fine, but the color itself is a black (instead of the expected grey from the input `awt.Color`). The API only mentions an `int` color, i wrongly assumend they mean the index : https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/RegionUtil.html

How do i provide the correct `int` value (based on my input `awt.Color`)so the bordercolor is the same one as in my normal cellstyle?

Code for setting up the merged borders

```
private void setBordersToMergedCells(XSSFSheet in_sheet, java.awt.Color in_bordercolor) {
    int numMerged = in_sheet.getNumMergedRegions();

    for (int i = 0; i < numMerged; i++) {
        //this works
        CellRangeAddress mergedRegions = in_sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
        RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN, mergedRegions, in_sheet);
        RegionUtil.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN, mergedRegions, in_sheet);
        RegionUtil.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN, mergedRegions, in_sheet);
        RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN, mergedRegions, in_sheet);
        //this does not work
        RegionUtil.setLeftBorderColor(new XSSFColor(in_bordercolor).getIndex(), mergedRegions, in_sheet);
        RegionUtil.setRightBorderColor(new XSSFColor(in_bordercolor).getIndex(), mergedRegions, in_sheet);
        RegionUtil.setTopBorderColor(new XSSFColor(in_bordercolor).getIndex(), mergedRegions, in_sheet);
        RegionUtil.setBottomBorderColor(new XSSFColor(in_bordercolor).getIndex(), mergedRegions, in_sheet);           
    }
```

For comparison, here is how i set up my cellstyle using (given) awt colors (works perfectly):

```
protected XSSFCellStyle createBorderedStyleXLSX(Workbook in_wb, java.awt.Color in_bordercolor) {
    XSSFCellStyle style = (XSSFCellStyle) in_wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderColor(XSSFCellBorder.BorderSide.TOP, new XSSFColor(in_bordercolor));
    style.setBorderColor(XSSFCellBorder.BorderSide.BOTTOM, new XSSFColor(in_bordercolor));
    style.setBorderColor(XSSFCellBorder.BorderSide.LEFT, new XSSFColor(in_bordercolor));
    style.setBorderColor(XSSFCellBorder.BorderSide.RIGHT, new XSSFColor(in_bordercolor));
    return style;
}
```

Comment: Check `isIndexed()` of your newly created `XSSFColor`. I would assume that it has no index or defaults to 0. You are probably looking for `IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not looking for a specific color, the color is a given awt color depending on my input. However, i tried the line `RegionUtil.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.GREY_80_PERCENT.getIndex(), mergedRegions, in_sheet);` and surprisingly, it didn't fix it but instead changed my whole cells to black (which is quite strange, since it should affect only borders?).

Comment: This is not possible until now. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126788/not-able-to-set-custom-color-in-xssfcell-apache-poi/45127209#45127209. Your new created `XSSFColor` are not indexed. So this cannot work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712340/apply-fill-colors-and-borders-to-excel-range-using-apache-poi/50762030#50762030 for a working example using `PropertyTemplate`

Comment: Thank you for your examples, i will dive into them deeper after some sleep. I think something might be off with my region merger, since they turn black when i add the index of an indexedColor. For now i "solved" it with an ugly hack by adding another row of empty cells after the header whose cellstyle only contains the left border style and color...