# SpreadsheetFormatRows format color ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, apache-poi, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

I'm creating Excel files using ColdFusion and the SpreadsheetNew, SpreadsheetAddRows, SpreadsheetFormatRows, etc. functions.  According to the docs that I have read located [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6747.html) their is a propery for color, and fgcolor.  I'm a bit confused as to what the difference between the two are.  Is one the text color and the other the background color?  I've been using fgcolor to set the background color of rows.

```
// HEADER ROW FORMAT
formatHeaderRow = StructNew();
formatHeaderRow.fgcolor="royal_blue";
```

My main question is, according to the docs I can supply any value in the `org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor` color class as my color.  However, I REALLY need to supply either a HEX value or RGB.  I know Excel can handle it as you can enter either within excel's colorpicker.  Is there ANY way to enter a HEX or RGB value for my row colors?

thank you!

**UPDATE**

```
<cfscript>
// create XLSX workbook with a few cells
// and grab underlying POI objects
cfSheet = Spreadsheetnew("Sheet1", true);
poiWorkbook = cfSheet.getWorkBook();
poiSheet = poiWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");


// Create reusuable style objects 
// NOTE: Excel limits the maximum number of styles allowed. So do not create a new
// style for every cell. Create distinct styles once, and apply to multiple cells/rows.
Color = createObject("java", "java.awt.Color");

// Style 1: Cell with background color (only)
backgroundOnlyStyle = poiWorkbook.createCellStyle();
backgroundOnlyStyle.setFillPattern( backgroundOnlyStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
XSSFColor = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor");
backgroundOnlyStyle.setFillForegroundColor( XSSFColor.init(Color.decode("##055910")) );

// Apply styles to cell A1. Note: POI indexes are 0-based
SpreadSheetSetCellValue(cfSheet, "background color only", 1, 1);
poiSheet.getRow( 0 ).setRowStyle( backgroundOnlyStyle );


</cfscript>

<!--- stream it to the browser --->
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=reportName.xlsx">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" variable="#SpreadSheetReadBinary(cfSheet)#">
```

Comment: Any particular version of ColdFusion. The documentation link goes to CF 9

Comment: Hm... good question.  [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37734884/104223) assumes CF11.  CF9 uses an older version of POI, so I am not sure if those same methods exist.

Comment: @JamesAMohler - I'm using CF 10, I believe Leigh's answer will work out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm a bit confused as to what the difference between the two are.

Understandably. The property names were modeled after the conventions used in [POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) (underlying java library) which are a bit confusing to begin with IMO. Since ColdFusion only implements a subset of the POI features, the names are taken out of context, making it even more confusing. To answer your question, in POI there are actually *three* (3) relevant color properties here:

1. **Font Color** - ie [`Font.setColor()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html#setColor(short))

   The color of the cell text. In CF, this is controlled by the `dataFormat.color` property.
2. **Cell Pattern Foreground Color** - ie [`CellStyle.setFillForegroundColor`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setFillForegroundColor(short))

   Despite the name, this is what most people think of as the cell *background* color (yellow in the image below). In CF this is controlled by the `dataFormat.fgColor` property.
3. **Cell Pattern Background Color** - [`CellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setFillBackgroundColor(short))

   (Optional) Secondary color used in multi-color cell patterns (red in the image below). There is no ColdFusion equivalent.

[image: Excel Cell Fill Properties]

> Is there ANY way to enter a HEX or RGB value for my row colors?

Last I checked it is not supported by the core CF functions. However, you could tap into the underlying POI library which [does support it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10924483/104223). Assuming you are using the newer .XLSX format, it can be done by creating a [CellStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html) and applying the desired [XSSFColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html).

Here is an example (tested with CF11) of how to set the font and/or cell background colors via POI. Though in the real code, I would recommend wrapping up the basic logic in a reusable function.

**Example:**

```
// create XLSX workbook with a few cells
// and grab underlying POI objects
cfSheet = Spreadsheetnew("Sheet1", true);
poiWorkbook = cfSheet.getWorkBook();
poiSheet = poiWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");


// Create reusuable style objects 
// NOTE: Excel limits the maximum number of styles allowed. So do not create a new
// style for every cell. Create distinct styles once, and apply to multiple cells/rows.
Color = createObject("java", "java.awt.Color");

// Style 1: Cell with background color (only)
backgroundOnlyStyle = poiWorkbook.createCellStyle();
backgroundOnlyStyle.setFillPattern( backgroundOnlyStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
XSSFColor = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor");
backgroundOnlyStyle.setFillForegroundColor( XSSFColor.init(Color.decode("##055910")) );

// Style 2: Cell with font color (only)
textOnlyStyle = poiWorkbook.createCellStyle();
textFont = poiWorkbook.createFont();
XSSFColor = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor");
textFont.setColor( XSSFColor.init(Color.decode("##bd13be")) );
textOnlyStyle.setFont( textFont );

// Style 3: Cell with both backgound and Text color
backgroundAndTextStyle = poiWorkbook.createCellStyle();
textFont = poiWorkbook.createFont();
XSSFColor = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor");
textFont.setColor( XSSFColor.init(Color.decode("##a20932")) );
backgroundAndTextStyle.setFont( textFont );
XSSFColor = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor");
backgroundAndTextStyle.setFillPattern( backgroundAndTextStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
backgroundAndTextStyle.setFillForegroundColor( XSSFColor.init(Color.decode("##192fda")) );

// Apply styles to cell A1. Note: POI indexes are 0-based
SpreadSheetSetCellValue(cfSheet, "background color only", 1, 1);
poiSheet.getRow( 0 ).getCell( 0 ).setCellStyle( backgroundOnlyStyle );

// Apply styles to cell A2
SpreadSheetSetCellValue(cfSheet, "text color only", 2, 1);
poiSheet.getRow( 1 ).getCell( 0 ).setCellStyle( textOnlyStyle );

// Apply styles to cell A3
SpreadSheetSetCellValue(cfSheet, "background AND text color", 3, 1);
poiSheet.getRow( 2 ).getCell( 0 ).setCellStyle( backgroundAndTextStyle );

// Save to file
SpreadSheetWrite(cfSheet, "c:/path/to/yourFile.xlsx", true);
```

Comment: how would I use your example to format an entire row?

Comment: [poiSheet.getRow( 2 ).setRowStyle( backgroundAndTextStyle );](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRow.html#setRowStyle(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle))

Comment: if I take your code above and replace the first .setCellStyle(textOnlyStyle) with a .setRowStyle(textOnlyStyle) it throws error that the .setRowStyle method was not found.  I'm not seeing it when I do a writeDump(poiSheet.getRow(0)); either

Comment: for whatever reason I cant seem to Save my trycf.com post so I added the code above to this post.  If you paste that into trycf.com and run under ColdFusion 10, you'll see the error - method just doesn't exist.  Works fine in newer versions though.

Comment: I'm just going to call setCellStyle on EACH cell, I cant see any other way of getting this to work.

Comment: Got it.  I see the problem. Unfortunately it is due to a difference in the POI version used by CF10 and 11. I am using CF11.  CF10 is bundled with a slightly older version that must not have implemented `setRowStyle()` yet. Applying it to each cell is fine. That is what I was going to suggest if you could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Over the weekend, our organization upgraded from ACF11 to ACF2018 and I found that the accepted answer given no longer works because the code has been deprecated and is no longer functional.  ACF2018 uses an updated version of the **Apache POI Utility** from ACF11.  Apparently the `SOLID_FOREGROUND` property has been removed from the `CellStyle`object and moved to the `FillPatternType` object.  I just wanted to provide an update to the accepted answer given by @Leigh back in 2016.  BTW, many thanks to @Leigh for providing a great code sample that worked for several years.  Hopefully this answer will save someone from future grief when updating to newer versions of ACF.

According to the docs from version 3.17 that field was removed.

```
Use FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND instead.

From source code of apache-poi 3.15 I can see:

/**
 * Fill Pattern: Solidly filled
 * @deprecated 3.15 beta 3. Use {@link FillPatternType#SOLID_FOREGROUND} instead.
 */
@Removal(version="3.17")
static final short SOLID_FOREGROUND = 1; //FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND;
```

I modified @Leigh's code above and added the following line

```
FillPatternType = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType");
```

I then modifed the following 2 lines

```
backgroundOnlyStyle.setFillPattern( backgroundOnlyStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
...
backgroundAndTextStyle.setFillPattern( backgroundAndTextStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
```

and changed them to

```
backgroundOnlyStyle.setFillPattern( FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
...
backgroundAndTextStyle.setFillPattern( FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
```

I created a working example and gist of @Leigh's code and verified it works in all versions of ACF from ACF10 up to ACF2018.
https://trycf.com/gist/cb4edf103a75b60e0d62259b0f9941ff/acf2018?theme=monokai

```
<cfscript>
// create XLSX workbook with a few cells
// and grab underlying POI objects
cfSheet = Spreadsheetnew("Sheet1", true);
poiWorkbook = cfSheet.getWorkBook();
poiSheet = poiWorkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");


// Create reusuable style objects 
// NOTE: Excel limits the maximum number of styles allowed. So do not create a new
// style for every cell. Create distinct styles once, and apply to multiple cells/rows.
Color = createObject("java", "java.awt.Color");
FillPatternType = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType");

// Style 1: Cell with background color (only)
backgroundOnlyStyle = poiWorkbook.createCellStyle();
backgroundOnlyStyle.setFillPattern( FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
XSSFColor = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor");
backgroundOnlyStyle.setFillForegroundColor( XSSFColor.init(Color.decode("##055910")) );

// Style 2: Cell with font color (only)
textOnlyStyle = poiWorkbook.createCellStyle();
textFont = poiWorkbook.createFont();
XSSFColor = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor");
textFont.setColor( XSSFColor.init(Color.decode("##bd13be")) );
textOnlyStyle.setFont( textFont );

// Style 3: Cell with both backgound and Text color
backgroundAndTextStyle = poiWorkbook.createCellStyle();
textFont = poiWorkbook.createFont();
XSSFColor = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor");
textFont.setColor( XSSFColor.init(Color.decode("##a20932")) );
backgroundAndTextStyle.setFont( textFont );
XSSFColor = createObject("java", "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor");
backgroundAndTextStyle.setFillPattern( FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
backgroundAndTextStyle.setFillForegroundColor( XSSFColor.init(Color.decode("##192fda")) );

// Apply styles to cell A1. Note: POI indexes are 0-based
SpreadSheetSetCellValue(cfSheet, "background color only", 1, 1);
poiSheet.getRow( 0 ).getCell( 0 ).setCellStyle( backgroundOnlyStyle );

// Apply styles to cell A2
SpreadSheetSetCellValue(cfSheet, "text color only", 2, 1);
poiSheet.getRow( 1 ).getCell( 0 ).setCellStyle( textOnlyStyle );

// Apply styles to cell A3
SpreadSheetSetCellValue(cfSheet, "background AND text color", 3, 1);
poiSheet.getRow( 2 ).getCell( 0 ).setCellStyle( backgroundAndTextStyle );

</cfscript>

<!--- Now that spreadsheet is prepared, initiate download --->  
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=yourfile.xlsx">
<cfcontent variable="#spreadsheetReadBinary(cfSheet)#" type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
```