# ColdFusion 2021 SpreadsheetFormatCell colors

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

Recently upgraded to CF2021 from CF11. I have a spreadsheet that we format cells, rows, and columns with colors, particularly background colors. I specify either color= or fgcolor=. No matter what color I choose, it will be black. I've searched and searched but find nothing for 2021.

Anybody have a solution?

Very simplified code. It works in CF11 and CF2016.

```
<cfscript>
    sObj = SpreadsheetNew("Testing Summary","yes");
    SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sObj,"As of: " & DateFormat(#DateAdd("h", -1, Now())#),1,1); 
    SpreadsheetFormatCell(sObj, {bold="true", fontsize="14"}, 1,1);
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(sObj,1,1,1,5);
    SpreadsheetSetCellValue(sObj,"Testing Summary",2,1); 
    SpreadsheetMergeCells(sObj,2,2,1,5);
    SpreadsheetFormatCell(sObj, {bold="true", fontsize="20", fgcolor="blue", color="yellow"}, 2,1);
</cfscript>

<!--- Launch File to User --->

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=MySpreadsheet.xlsx"> 
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.ms-excel" variable="#SpreadsheetReadBinary( sObj )#">
```

Comment: Check out LuceeSpreadsheet project on GitHub. I’ve had a lot better experience with this library versus CFSpreadsheet.

Comment: Looks like a bug in 2021. This is not an issue in 2018. Please report bug on https://tracker.adobe.com .

Comment: Adobe bundled CF2021 with a new version of POI. Some of the underlying POI classes changed, but looks like Adobe didn't catch that, breaking the function.  You should file a bug report. Until it's fixed, either try the Lucee option or diy with java instead.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727645/spreadsheetformatrows-format-color-coldfusion

Comment: For anyone else encountering [the bug was fixed in "HF1 for CF2021"](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4211061).

Comment: I applied the HF1 with lots of effort due to my setup being behind firewalls. You need internet access to get bundles/packages updated. The fix does not include the bundle/packages offline. It will break your your site. I had to work days with Adobe to get a 350Mb file through my firewall.